# How to show in the #posts div the posts that belong to the clicked category with the append method?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a menu with some post categories:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($categories->get() as $category)
        <li class="ative">
            <a href="#" name="category" id="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</a>
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

When I click in the category, for example with id "1", through the menu I want to show the posts that belong to the category with id "1"in the "#posts" div.

So, the #posts div shows the last posts when the page is acessed at first, but after a category is clicked it should show the posts that belong to the clicked category. So I have the #posts div:

```
<div id="posts">
    @foreach($posts as $post)
    <div id="posts">
         <img src="{{$post->image}}">
        <h1>{{$post->title}}</h1>
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

If the category with id "1" is clicked in the console appears the info of the only post that exist for now for that category with id "1":

```
{id: 1, title: "Title", description: "", …}
```

Now do you know how to show in the #posts div the posts that belong to the clicked category with the append method? Something like below (but like below dont works):

```
$('#posts').append(
    <div id="posts">
      <img src="{{$post->image}}">
      <h1>{{$post->title}}</h1>                    
     </div>);
 });
```

I have a FrontController index method that shows the homepage:

```
public function index(){
        return view('home')
            ->with('categories', Category::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get())
            ->with('posts', Post::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get());
    }
```

I also have a PostController that has a method postsFromCategory to get the posts from a selected category:

```
 public function WhereHasCategory(Request $request)
    {
        $posts = Post::whereHas('categories', function ($categories) use (&$request) {
            $categories->where('category_post.id',$request->id);
        })->get();
        return response()->json($posts);
    }
```

Then in the index.blade.php I have the ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '{{ route('category.posts',null) }}/' + category_id,
    type: 'GET',
    success:function(result){
        $('#posts').empty();
        $.each(result,function(index, post){
            //$('#posts').append(<span>post.title</span>);
        });
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(error.status)
    }
});
```

Comment: Change `<div class="post">` to `<div id="posts">`

Comment: Thanks, it was a typo. I update the question to change that.

Comment: Hey, If I understand well you are trying to show all the post related to the post category selected from the server (php )?

Comment: Yes, show all posts that related to the clicked category in the menu.

Comment: Since the post belongsTo the category you could do `$posts = Post::where('category_id', $request->category_id)->get();`

Comment: Is it typo or really the class name is ative `<li class="ative">`?

Comment: please share all the javascript to help you, because apparently you have another issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build up the html in the `each` method and then append it to the `posts` div

```
$('#posts').empty();

var newPosts = '';

$.each(result, function(index, post) {
    newPosts += '<img src="' + post.image + '">' +
             + '<h1>' + post.title + '</h1>';
});

$("#posts").html(newPosts);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it appears this error "Use of undefined constant post - assumed 'post'".

Comment: @AdamK could you post the output of  `console.log(result);`

Comment: It appears: VM2064:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: result is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13.

Comment: But when the category with id 1 is clicked it appears: [{…}]
0
:
{id: 1, title: "Title", description: "", post_date: "2018-03-10 10:30:00", …}
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Array(0).

Comment: So you need to fire the `ajax` on the click event of category

Comment: Can you explain how that is different of the code in the question? There is the url "    url: '{{ route('category.posts',null) }}/' + category_id,".

Answer (score 2):

Try to change this line,I don't know if this is a typo, but you need to send a string to append function and then use the variable from javascript not from the php.

```
//$('#posts').append(<span>post.title</span>);
```

to:

```
$('#posts').append('<div id="posts">' +
  '<img src="'+ post.image +'">' +
  '<h1>'+ post.title +'</h1>' +                    
 '</div>');
```

Comment: Thanks, but like that appears "Use of undefined constant post - assumed 'post'".

Comment: Did you copy and pasted ?

Comment: Yes, it seems that the variable post dont have the properties title, etc.

Comment: interesting, if your are getting the right information in the variable result, try with `result.forEach( function(post) { /* the code */})`

Comment: can you share the content of result variable ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167891/discussion-between-julio-guerra-and-adamk).